# What's the fastest alternative in R to do this string regex processing?

Tags: r, xml, parsing, bigdata, tidyverse

I'm dealing with 75GB XML files i.e. it's therefore impossible to load them in memory and build a DOM XML tree. Therefore I resort to processing chunks of lines (using `readr::read_lines_chunked`) in blocks of e.g. 10k lines. This is a small demonstration of N=3 lines where I extract the data needed to build the `tibble`, but this isn't super fast:

```
library(tidyverse)
xml <- c("<row Id=\"4\" Attrib1=\"1\" Attrib2=\"7\" Attrib3=\"2008-07-31T21:42:52.667\" Attrib4=\"645\" Attrib5=\"45103\" Attrib6=\"fjbnjahkcbvahjsvdghvadjhavsdjbaJKHFCBJHABCJKBASJHcvbjavbfcjkhabcjkhabsckajbnckjasbnckjbwjhfbvjahsdcvbzjhvcbwiebfewqkn\" Attrib7=\"8\" Attrib8=\"11652943\" Attrib9=\"Rich B\" Attrib10=\"2019-09-03T17:25:25.207\" Attrib11=\"2019-10-21T14:03:54.607\" Attrib12=\"1\" Attrib13=\"a|b|c|d|e|f|g\" Attrib14=\"13\" Attrib15=\"3\" Attrib16=\"49\" Attrib17=\"2012-10-31T16:42:47.213\"/>",
         "<row Id=\"5\" Attrib1=\"2\" Attrib2=\"8\" Attrib3=\"2008-07-31T21:42:52.999\" Attrib4=\"649\" Attrib5=\"7634\" Attrib6=\"fjbnjahkcbvahjsvdghvadjhavsdjbaJKHFCBJHABCJKBASJHcvbjavbfcjkhabcjkhabsckajbnckjasbnckjbwjhfbvjahsdcvbzjhvcbwiebfewqkn\" Attrib7=\"8\" Attrib8=\"11652943\" Attrib9=\"Rich B\" Attrib10=\"2019-09-03T17:25:25.207\" Attrib11=\"2019-10-21T14:03:54.607\" Attrib12=\"2\" Attrib13=\"a|b|c|d|e|f|g\" Attrib14=\"342\" Attrib15=\"43\" Attrib16=\"767\" Attrib17=\"2012-10-31T16:42:47.213\"/>",
         "<row Id=\"6\" Attrib1=\"3\" Attrib2=\"9\" Attrib3=\"2008-07-31T21:42:52.999\" Attrib4=\"348\" Attrib5=\"2732\" Attrib6=\"djhfbsdjhfbijhsdbfjkdbnfkjndaskjfnskjdlnfkjlsdnf\" Attrib7=\"9\" Attrib8=\"34873\" Attrib9=\"FHDHsf\" Attrib10=\"2019-09-03T17:25:25.207\" Attrib11=\"2019-10-21T14:03:54.607\" Attrib12=\"3\" Attrib13=\"a|b|c|d|e|f|g\" Attrib14=\"342\" Attrib15=\"43\" Attrib16=\"767\" Attrib17=\"2012-10-31T16:42:47.4333\"/>")
pattern <- paste(".*(Id=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib1=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib2=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib3=\"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+T[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\") ",
                 "(Attrib4=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib5=\"\\d+\")",
                 ".*(Attrib8=\"\\d+\") ",
                 ".*(Attrib10=\"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+T[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\") ",
                 "(Attrib11=\"[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+T[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+.[0-9]+\")",
                 ".*(Attrib13=\"([a-z]|[0-9]|\\||\\s)+\") ",
                 "(Attrib14=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib15=\"\\d+\") ",
                 "(Attrib16=\"\\d+\")",
                 sep="")
# match the groups in pattern and extract the matches
tmp <- str_match(xml, pattern)[,-c(1,12)]
# remove non matching NA rows  
r <- which(is.na(tmp[,1]))
if (length(r) > 0) {
  tmp <- tmp[-r,]
}
# remove the metadata and stay with the data within the double quotes only
tmp <- apply(tmp, 1, function(s) {
  str_remove_all(str_match(s, "(\".*\")")[,-1], "\"")
})
# need the transposed version of tmp
tmp <- t(tmp)
tmp
# convert to a tibble
colnames(tmp) <- c("Id", "Attrib1", "Attrib2", "Attrib3", "Attrib4", "Attrib5", "Attrib8", "Attrib10", "Attrib11", "Attrib13", "Attrib14", "Attrib15", "Attrib16")
as_tibble(tmp)
```

Is there a better approach performance-wise?

**UPDATE:** I benchmarked the code above on 10k lines (instead of 3) and it was 900 seconds. I then reduced the number of attribute regex groups from 13 to 7 (only the critically important ones) and the same benchmark dropped to 128 seconds.

Extrapolating to 9731474 lines I went from ~10 days to ~35 hours. I then split the big file into 6 files using the Linux command `split -l1621913 -d Huge.xml Huge_split_ --verbose` to match the number of cores I have and now running the code in parallel on each split file ... so I'm looking at 35/6=~5.8 hours ... which is not too bad. I do:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(6)
resultList <- foreach (i=0:5) %dopar% {
  file <- sprintf('Huge_split_0%d', i)  
  partial <- # run the chunk algorithm on file
  return(partial)
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to solve this with regex? That seems to parse relatively fine with [`xml2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html), and if you have post-XML regex adjustments *per-column*, then they can be done much more efficiently.

Comment: @r2evans the XML file is 75GB, that's why. I can't load such file in memory. What I provided is a small 3 row sample of the data so people can see what I am doing right now ... there are another 9'731'474 rows like that.

Comment: I loaded those three strings, wrapped them with `<xml>` and `</xml>` (sloppy, perhaps), and `xml2::read_xml` read them just fine. If you need the actual parent node nomenclature, you can always keep it on the first read then re-use it when you window/roll through the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xml2`, I'm able to get significantly better processing times, especially with larger scale. Since I'm not fully proficient with `xml2`, there is likely another way of doing this a little better.

```r
library(stringr)
func_regex <- function(xmlvec) {
  tmp <- str_match(xmlvec, pattern)[,-c(1,12)]
  # remove non matching NA rows  
  r <- which(is.na(tmp[,1]))
  if (length(r) > 0) {
    tmp <- tmp[-r,]
  }
  # remove the metadata and stay with the data within the double quotes only
  tmp <- apply(tmp, 1, function(s) {
    str_remove_all(str_match(s, "(\".*\")")[,-1], "\"")
  })
  # need the transposed version of tmp
  tmp <- as.data.frame(t(tmp))
  colnames(tmp) <- c("Id", "Attrib1", "Attrib2", "Attrib3", "Attrib4", "Attrib5", "Attrib8", "Attrib10", "Attrib11", "Attrib13", "Attrib14", "Attrib15", "Attrib16")
  tmp
}

library(xml2)
func_xml2 <- function(xmlvec) {
  as.data.frame(do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(xml_children(read_xml(paste("<xml>", paste(xmlvec, collapse=""), "</xml>"))),
           function(x) xml_attrs(x))
  ))
}
```

(**Edit**: I realize I'm reaching out from `func_regex` to use `pattern`, a sloppy breach of scope. Perhaps I'll fix it and update the benchmarking, I don't think it'll improve the relative speed improvement of `xml2`.)

Similar-enough output:

```r
str(func_regex(xml))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ Id      : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib1 : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib2 : Factor w/ 3 levels "7","8","9": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "2008-07-31T21:42:52.667",..: 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib4 : Factor w/ 3 levels "348","645","649": 2 3 1
#  $ Attrib5 : Factor w/ 3 levels "2732","45103",..: 2 3 1
#  $ Attrib8 : Factor w/ 2 levels "11652943","34873": 1 1 2
#  $ Attrib10: Factor w/ 1 level "2019-09-03T17:25:25.207": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib11: Factor w/ 1 level "2019-10-21T14:03:54.607": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib13: Factor w/ 1 level "a|b|c|d|e|f|g": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib14: Factor w/ 2 levels "13","342": 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib15: Factor w/ 2 levels "3","43": 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib16: Factor w/ 2 levels "49","767": 1 2 2

str(func_xml2(xml))
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  18 variables:
#  $ Id      : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib1 : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib2 : Factor w/ 3 levels "7","8","9": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "2008-07-31T21:42:52.667",..: 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib4 : Factor w/ 3 levels "348","645","649": 2 3 1
#  $ Attrib5 : Factor w/ 3 levels "2732","45103",..: 2 3 1
#  $ Attrib6 : Factor w/ 2 levels "djhfbsdjhfbijhsdbfjkdbnfkjndaskjfnskjdlnfkjlsdnf",..: 2 2 1
#  $ Attrib7 : Factor w/ 2 levels "8","9": 1 1 2
#  $ Attrib8 : Factor w/ 2 levels "11652943","34873": 1 1 2
#  $ Attrib9 : Factor w/ 2 levels "FHDHsf","Rich B": 2 2 1
#  $ Attrib10: Factor w/ 1 level "2019-09-03T17:25:25.207": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib11: Factor w/ 1 level "2019-10-21T14:03:54.607": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib12: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
#  $ Attrib13: Factor w/ 1 level "a|b|c|d|e|f|g": 1 1 1
#  $ Attrib14: Factor w/ 2 levels "13","342": 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib15: Factor w/ 2 levels "3","43": 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib16: Factor w/ 2 levels "49","767": 1 2 2
#  $ Attrib17: Factor w/ 2 levels "2012-10-31T16:42:47.213",..: 1 1 2
```

Benchmarking:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  func_regex(xml),
  func_xml2(xml),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr    min     lq    mean  median     uq    max neval
#  func_regex(xml) 1.4306 1.4728 1.57756 1.48660 1.5875 2.2086    10
#   func_xml2(xml) 1.0714 1.1075 1.18385 1.15275 1.1875 1.5418    10

xml1000 <- rep(xml, 1000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  func_regex(xml1000),
  func_xml2(xml1000),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  func_regex(xml1000) 458.4921 531.1159 570.1703 534.8204 538.6754 782.6863    10
#   func_xml2(xml1000) 107.1230 107.7632 110.7316 109.1315 111.1904 121.8560    10

xml100000 <- rep(xml, 100000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  func_regex(xml100000),
  func_xml2(xml100000),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: seconds
#                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  func_regex(xml100000) 52.89568 53.97438 55.64431 54.67441 56.95971 61.86949    10
#   func_xml2(xml100000) 13.77857 16.02327 16.50498 16.58733 17.38458 17.81042    10
```

Comment: thank you so much for this great answer. In my PC the speed up of your solution is orders of magnitude faster!